# Printed Firefox page breaks with CSS grid element longer than one printed page

Tags: html, css, firefox, browser

Firefox appears to have an issue with printing a web page when there's an element that breaks across printed pages that has `display: grid`. For some reason, this creates an unavoidable page-break before the element (even when using `page-break-before: avoid`). This only appears to happen in Firefox, it behaves as expected in Chrome and Edge.

Here is a minimal example of what I'm working with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <style>     
            .tableContainer {
                display: grid;
                page-break-before: avoid;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div> Some content </div>
        <div class="tableContainer">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Header 1</th>
                    <th>Header 2</th>
                    <th>Header 3</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                </tr>

                //Repeat table rows until table reaches over the first printed page
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

`display: block` in a media print query will adjust the layout in this example but that isn't a feasible solution in this project as it will disrupt other pages and needlessly apply it to other browsers which print the pages fine.

Is this is a bug with Firefox or is there a fix?